# Integrating a HTML css code to domain

Tags: html, file-transfer

I ve got some knowledge in writing html and css so my friend wanted me to design something for him.But I dont have much knowledge about file transfer etc so I dont know how can I push my files to that domain and I could not find a trustable method in google.So basically how can I put my html code into a domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing a piece of software that can do FTP for transferring files to/from a server would be the first place to look.

I personally use [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org)

You'll need the details of the web server and account to login.

Comment: I once did something like that for my homework.First I connected to a website with putty,logged into it.Then I created a file public_html with mkdir command and give everyone read permission.After that I used CyberDuck to add files to public_html.Is it the same process

Comment: @Curriculaa Yes CyberDuck is another example of FTP software used for uploading/downloading files from a server.

Comment: One more question.The sites name is esportshowdown.com which gives a message like this when I try to enter. This site is under development

This page indicates the webmaster has not uploaded a website to the server.

For information on how to build or upload a site, please visit your web hosting company's site. And the domain is bought from domain.com.So where should I connect when I try to move files into the website.I am guessing it should be to domain.com but I couldnt figure it out

Comment: You will need to upload the website files to the web server. You'll also need to login to your domain name provider to link your domain name to your web server.

Comment: I figured it out thanks for the answer though.I accept your answer

Comment: Many Thanks, hope it all goes well for you @Curriculaa